# If a batted ball strikes a runner on the offensive team and is caught before hitting the ground by the defense, is this an out?

Tags: rules, baseball, officiating

If a batted ball strikes a runner on the offensive team (assume that the ball already went by an infielder, nullifying any interference) and is caught before hitting the ground by the defense, is this an out?

Conversely, what happens if the ball strikes a runner leading off third completely in foul territory and is caught before hitting the ground? Is this just an immediate dead ball since it struck a person in foul territory?

Comment: Second part of question is duplicate of https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/16416/third-base-runner-gets-hit-by-a-foul-ball-is-he-out/

Answer (score -1):

Live ball, no out.

**From MLB (6.09)(a)(4) When the Batter Becomes a Runner**

> A fair ball, after having passed a fielder other than the pitcher, or after having been touched by a fielder, including the pitcher, shall touch an umpire or runner on fair territory;

Comment: There's a huge amount of context missing because of the limited rule quote. You haven't explained why this rule excludes the out either.